# Error when calling to source in user control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Im using the following code which is run on the main window as expected .

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public  ObservableCollection<User> _UsersList = new ObservableCollection<User>();
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _mapping = new Dictionary<string, string>();


    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        _UsersList.Add(new User { Name = "Darl" });

        CollectionViewSource source = this.Resources["source"] as CollectionViewSource;
        source.Source = _UsersList;
        ListBox.SelectionChanged += listbox_SelectionChanged;
```

Now I want to change it and use the code in user control and I do as follows

public partial class UC: UserControl
    {

```
    private static ModelView ModelViewInstance;

    public Uc()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ModelViewInstance = new MappingViewModelView();
        DataContext = ModelViewInstance;
        CollectionViewSource source = this.Resources["source"] as CollectionViewSource;
        source.Source = ModelViewInstance.UserList;
```

I when I run this program I got exception in the `source.Source = ModelViewInstance.UserList;`

I need this code since when I omit it and run the program I don't have exception but

this code return null for the user object which is not happen if I use the main window program instead the user control

```
private void DropText_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    var textbox = (TextBox) sender;
    if (!(textbox.Text.Length > 0))
    {
        DataObject data = e.Data as DataObject;
        User user = data.GetData(typeof(User)) as User;
        textbox.Tag = user;
```

I have another class like model view with user which defined as observer collection ,

How can I avoid this dump?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to achieve however just to let you know.. in no way is that code 'MVVM'.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul, yeah I think it's just a fashion thing... it's just 'happening' now for all new WPF developers to claim that they are using MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

If you originally declared your `source CollectionViewSource` in the `Window.Resources` section, but you didn't move your `Resources` from the `Window` to the `UserControl`, then your problem could well be caused by a `null` reference to the `source CollectionViewSource`. If this is the case, then try moving your `source CollectionViewSource` to the `UserControl.Resources` section and running your application again.

---

UPDATE >>>

If your `ListBox` named `ListBox` is in the `UserControl` then you can't reach it from `MainWindow`. Instead, you need to move the `listbox_SelectionChanged` code to the `UserControl` code behind. But really, you're still doing it wrong. You should be creating a `DependencyProperty` in the `UserControl` to bind the collection to; the `UserControl` displays the contents, but you can still add or remove items from the collection from the `MainWindow` because that's where the collection is.